# Oxyplot does not display plots in WPF view

Tags: c#, wpf, plot, oxyplot

I'm working with OxyPlot in WPF. Trying to display PlotModels in a UI.
Sometimes the plot is displayed in the UI and sometimes not.

This code is used to initialize the `PlotModel` by a `BackgroundWorker`:

ViewModel:

```
this.pm = setUpModel();
data2plot();
```

With the methods:

```
private PlotModel _pm;
public PlotModel pm
{
     get { return _pm; }
     set { _pm= value; RaisePropertyChanged("pm"); }
}


private PlotModel setUpModel()
{
      PlotModel pm = new PlotModel();
      pm.IsLegendVisible = false;
      var xAxis= new CategoryAxis();          
      pm.Axes.Add(xAxis);
      var valueAxis = new LinearAxis();            
      pm.Axes.Add(valueAxis);
      return pm ;
}

//tbl holds the data in the second column
private void data2plot(DataTable tbl)
{
       var series = new OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries();
       int i = 0;
       foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
       {
             double val = double.Parse(row[1].ToString());
             series.Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, val));
             i++;
       }

       this.pm.Series.Add(series);
}
```

Code used in View to initialize the model:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="205" Margin="10,117,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="308">
       <oxypl:PlotView x:Name="plot" Model="{Binding pm,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Margin="10" Grid.Row="1">
       </oxypl:PlotView>
</Grid>
```

with the following references

```
xmlns:oxypl="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ViewModel}"
```

The Binding works, so I guess there have to be a problem with my `PlotModel`.

I don't know if this is relevant, but the `DataTable tbl` is initialized by the `Lazy<T>` class (with `isThreadSafe=true`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add to your `pm` member, the value of `pm` is not being updated - it's the content of that member that is updated, i.e. the setter is never called, so the RaisePropertyChanged event is never emitted and the view isn't notified of any change.  Suggest you build a local set of data and then overwrite `pm` with a complete set of data at the end, or emit a `RaisePropertyChanged` event when you're done.

The reason that it is working sometimes I would guess is that the first (and only) time the view reads the content back from the viewmodel you've already populated it, so you see something, but then no updates.

Comment: No problems.  You really have to be careful when working with bound collections in WPF, but now you know ...

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, I guess it worked just by chance. Any other ideas?

Comment: As before, sometimes it displays the plot, sometimes not.

Comment: Ok, have you used Snoop before?  Download and install 'Snoop WPF', then run your application up, run up Snoop, then Ctrl+Shift over your application where your plot should be appearing.  You will find all properties listed in there, and it will show you if the binding is still ok, or if you've broken it somehow

Comment: No I haven't, but it is not necessary anymore. The problem has been solved, by just adding the Oxyplot.Series to the PlotModel before initializing the property. (I don't know why it wasn't working by calling RaisePropertyChanged. So again: Thank you (:

Answer (score 1):

You also have to call

```
pm.InvalidatePlot(true);
```

after adding to the series, in order to trigger a redraw.